# Time-dependent quantum dynamics as dynamical system and ergodic therorems

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, quantum-mechanics

In full glory, a dynamical system is defined as a tuple $(T,M,\Phi)$ where $T$ is a monoid, written additively, $M$ is a set, and $\Phi$ is a function.
$$ \Phi : U \subset T \times M \to M$$
with

$ I(x) = \{t \in T : (t,x) \in U \}$
$ \Phi(0,x) = x $
$ \Phi(t_2, \Phi(t_1(x))  = \Phi(t_1 + t_2, x)$ for $t_1, t_2,t_1+t_2 \in I(x)$

See [this Math stack exchange post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475462/dynamical-systems).

I am interested in quantum dynamics generated by a Hamiltonian that could be time-dependent, that is, a quantum state in a $d$-dimensional Hilbert space evolving via the Schrodinger equation
\begin{align}
i \partial_t |\psi(t)\rangle = H(t)|\psi(t)\rangle
\end{align}
with initial state $|\psi(0)\rangle$.
The solution is $|\psi(t)\rangle = U(t) |\psi(0)\rangle$ where $U(t)$ is the unitary time-evolution operator which is formally given as a time-ordered exponential
\begin{align}
U(t) = \mathcal{T}e^{-i\int_0^t H(t') dt'}.
\end{align}

My question is: **does this constitute an example of a dynamical system?**

My understanding is, if the Hamiltonian is time-independent $H(t) = H$, then yes. This is because $U(t) = e^{-iHt}$ so $U(t+s) = U(t)U(s)$. If the Hamiltonian has non-trivial time-dependence, then no, according to [Is the initial value problem of an ODE considered as a dynamic system?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240143/is-the-initial-value-problem-of-an-ode-considered-as-a-dynamic-system?rq=1).
This is because $U(t)$ fails the semi-group property in general.
Would my understanding be right?

The reason I am interested in asking this is because I am interested in ergodic theorems (e.g., Birkhoff's, point wise ergodic, Von Neumann ergodic theorems). But it seems to me they all deal with dynamical systems, in particular, with the flow map  $\Phi$ satisfying the semigroup property. My next question is: **are there any ergodic theorems in the case when the semigroup property does not hold?**

Comment: One can design a time-dependent Hamiltonian in which time averages do not even exist. You can make observables oscillate in specific ways that prevent their Césaro means from converging (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1440298/does-average-value-always-exist). So, without imposing additional constraints on the time dependence, there are no general ergodic theorems.

Answer (score 2):

For a time-dependent Hamiltonian you will need an evolution operator $U(t_2,t_1)= \mathcal{T}e^{-i\int_{t_1}^{t_2} H(t') dt'}$ that depends on initial and final times ($0<t_1<t_2$). With the composition property $U(t_2,t_1)U(t_1,0)=U(t_2,0)$ you can then consider this a non-stationary dynamical system.

The main difference between classical and quantum dynamical systems lies in the fact that the Hilbert space is typically infinite-dimensional. A formulation of quantum dynamical systems based on $C^\ast$ algebras is given by [Claude Pillet](https://hal.science/hal-00128867/document) (see section 4.4).

Comment: thanks. I am interested in the case of the Hilbert space being finite dimensional. Are there ergodic theorems for "non-stationary dynamical systems" then?

Comment: a typical definition of ergodicity implies stationarity, see for example the discussion at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/593746/87355